# Uploadifive jQuery Upload non-flash version

Tags: jquery, uploadify

Im using the jQuery Upload library uploadify non flash version called uploadifive I got it install but a weird problem when you click on the browse / Select file button nothing happens has any else ran into this problem and if so how to fix thank.
The HTML is basically simple just the upload input and a div tag

```
$(function() {
  $('#file_upload').uploadifive({
    'debug'             : true,
    'auto'              : true,
    'formData'          : {'test' : 'something'},
    'queueID'           : 'queue',
    'buttonText'        : 'ATTACH FILE',
    'uploadScript'      : '".base_application_url()."upload_license/',
    'onUploadComplete'  : function(file, data) {
    console.log(data);
     });
});
```

Comment: Try add options 'multi':false. Intuition tells me that it might be the case.

Comment: Does your html look like this: `<input id="file_upload" type="file" name="file_upload" />` ?

Comment: Also, if you're using a browser with developer extensions (chrome for example) you can press F12, then click on your select file button and see if any errors are thrown in the console.

Comment: Yes it dose. I also added the line to no success. any other ideas Thanks. also I use firefox for debuging but there is no message in the console

Comment: @user1074242 I think the "uploadScript" line is wrong. Try yo put a string. You are concatenating php in a js code

Comment: @user1074242, did you fix it?

Comment: Are you trying to use the uploader on a modal jquery dialog by chance?  If so, it won't work.  The solution is to initialize the dialog as non-modal.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

Change your code to this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#file_upload').uploadifive({
    'debug'             : true,
    'auto'              : true,
    'formData'          : {'test' : 'something'},
    'queueID'           : 'queue',
    'buttonText'        : 'ATTACH FILE',
    'uploadScript'      : '/upload_license',
    'onUploadComplete'  : function(file, data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
    'onFallback': function(){
      alert('HTML5 is not supported in this browser.');
    }
  });
});
```

## Descriptions

I've been using Uploadifive and it has worked out great. Although their examples and documentation all use PHP, I have been using it with .NET just as easily.

The first issue I see with your code is the `uploadScipt` value, which is equivalent to the `action` attribute in an HTML form. I can see you're trying to get the absolute URL from `".base_application_url()."upload_license/`, but you only need the relative URL, such as `/upload_license` or `/upload_license.php`. I am using it with .NET MVC4, so my `uploadScript` is set to `/upload`.

The other possibility is that your browser may not support the HTML5 version (could be outdated). For an easy test, add this options to when you initialize your uploader

```
'onFallback': function () {
    alert('HTML5 is not supported in this browser');
}
```

This code will display an alert if Uploadifive is not supported. If that is the case, download the flash version as well and initialize that in the `onFallback` callback.